# How to set the buffer size for trace_pipe in ftrace?

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, android-ndk

Basically there are two main ways to read ftrace logs. 
Either read from 
       /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace 
or read from 
       /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_pipe

The buffer size for former can be set using 
      /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/buffer_size_kb

Is it possible to set the buffer size for trace_pipe. If yes, how ?

Answer (score 1):

There is only one buffer, and `/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/buffer_size_kb` sets its size.

When you read from `../trace`, the kernel pauses tracing, freezes the buffer, and you read a copy of that buffer (containing all events from (`t1 - K` to `t1`).

When you read from `../trace_pipe`, you consume data from the tail end of the buffer and it is gone from the kernel. The kernel continues tracing and adding data to the head of the buffer, and your reader will just block waiting for that new data if it has consumed everything in the buffer already.

If there's no consumer (ie, before you start reading) and the buffer is full, the kernel will either drop from the tail of the buffer, or stop inserting new data at the head, depending on the value of `/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/options/overwrite`. Thus if `overwrite` is set to `1`, you will start getting events from `t1 - K`, otherwise you will read events starting from even earlier (when tracing was first enabled), and then have a gap, and then recent events starting at `t1`

Source: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/trace/ftrace.txt

Answer (score 0):

You do not require to set buffer size for trace_pipe as it gives live trace and blocks if there is no data available.

Read more on (https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/trace/ftrace.txt):

trace_pipe:

```
The output is the same as the "trace" file but this
file is meant to be streamed with live tracing.
Reads from this file will block until new data is
retrieved.  Unlike the "trace" file, this file is a
consumer. This means reading from this file causes
sequential reads to display more current data. Once
data is read from this file, it is consumed, and
will not be read again with a sequential read. The
"trace" file is static, and if the tracer is not
adding more data, it will display the same
information every time it is read.
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but you may not have understood my question properly. Let me clarify it again. My doubt is that if you start reading data from trace_pipe at timestamp, t1, then will it give ftrace logs from t1 time only or from t1-K time (K some constant).

Comment: what you have explained is true for trace; but not for trace_pipe.